# Ошибка при запуске Denwer

Tags: denwer

После обычной установки Denwer'а и запуска сервера в Windows 7 в трее появляется пару значков:[image: Системный трей Windows]

После нажатия на значок пера открывается консоль с сообщением о какой-то синтаксической ошибке:[image: Синтаксическая ошибка]

После 30-ти секундного отсчёта окно закрывается и значок в трее исчезает. И всё бы ничего, но при попытке открыть http://localhost в браузере выдаётся ошибка: [image: Окно Firefox при попытке открыть localhost]
Зайти в localhost не получается ни до, ни после ошибки в консоли.
Как исправить эту ошибку? В чём проблема? HELP!

Comment: лог запуска сервера можно увидеть?

Comment: А где они находятся?

Comment: запускаете денвер, заходите на localhost/denwer и там ищите раздел тестирование денвера. Там написан путь к файлам логов